Sending bribes to block validators
I've got a question regarding bribes. Is it possible to send a bribe without using block builders' RPCs like rpc.titanbuilder.com? I would like to send a transaction using my own node and land it at the beginning of the block, eg. first 10-20 spots or so and normally to achieve that I would have to send the transaction to the builder as a bundle. Will sending ETH to block.coinbase work?
The thing I want to achieve is to nearly always land in the next occuring block and normally it works by sending transactions to normal RPC, but then my position is at best around 40th spot. And when using the block builders' RPCs I dont always land in the next block.
I saw some spambots that send transactions to the public memepool and then when transaction is validated and succeeds they pay bribe, eg 0xdebd790052840a86a73daea08dda4d208d98ead4. This wallet is always super early in terms of position in the block.

There is no difference sending coinbase or using maxFeePerGas.
The maxFeePerGas is preferred to save gas.
